# Python-numpy test for ndarray using ndim

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on a project in Python requiring a lot of numerical array calculations.  Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your POV), I'm very new to Python, but have been doing MATLAB and Octave programming (APL before that) for years.  I'm very used to having every variable automatically typed to a matrix float, and still getting used to checking input types.

In many of my functions, I require the input S to be a `numpy.ndarray` of size `(n,p)`, so I have to  both test that type(S) is `numpy.ndarray` and get the values `(n,p) = numpy.shape(S)`.  One potential problem is that the input could be a list/tuple/int/etc..., another problem is that the input could be an array of shape `()`: `S.ndim = 0`.  It occurred to me that I could simultaneously test the variable type, fix the `S.ndim = 0`problem, then get my dimensions like this:

```
# first simultaneously test for ndarray and get proper dimensions
try:
    if (S.ndim == 0):
        S = S.copy(); S.shape = (1,1);
    # define dimensions p, and p2
    (p,p2) = numpy.shape(S);
except AttributeError:  # got here because input is not something array-like
    raise AttributeError("blah blah blah");
```

Though it works, I'm wondering if this is a valid thing to do?  The docstring for ndim says

> If it is not already an ndarray, a conversion is
>           attempted.

and we surely know that numpy can easily convert an int/tuple/list to an array, so I'm confused why an AttributeError is being raised for these types inputs, when numpy should be doing this

```
numpy.array(S).ndim;
```

which should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the comments to @larsmans answer, you could try:

```
if not isinstance(S, np.ndarray):
    raise TypeError("Input not a ndarray")
if S.ndim == 0:
    S = np.reshape(S, (1,1))
(p, p2) = S.shape
```

First, you check explicitly whether `S` is a (subclass of) `ndarray`. Then, you use the `np.reshape` to copy your data (and reshaping it, of course) if needed. At last, you get the dimension.

Note that in most cases, the `np` functions will first try to access the corresponding method of a `ndarray`, then attempt to convert the input to a `ndarray` (sometimes keeping it a subclass, as in `np.asanyarray`, sometimes not (as in `np.asarray(...)`). In other terms, it's always more efficient to use the method rather than the function: that's why we're using `S.shape` and not `np.shape(S)`.

Another point: the `np.asarray`, `np.asanyarray`, `np.atleast_1D`... are all particular cases of the more generic function `np.array`. For example, `asarray` sets the optional `copy` argument of `array` to `False`, `asanyarray` does the same and sets `subok=True`, `atleast_1D` sets `ndmin=1`, `atleast_2d` sets `ndmin=2`... In other terms, it's always easier to use `np.array` with the appropriate arguments. But as mentioned in some comments, it's a matter of style. Shortcuts can often improve readability, which is always an objective to keep in mind.

In any case, when you use `np.array(..., copy=True)`, you're explicitly asking for a copy of your initial data, a bit like doing a `list([....])`. Even if nothing else changed, your data will be copied. That has the advantages of its drawbacks (as we say in French), you could for example change the `order` from row-first `C` to column-first `F`. But anyway, you get the copy you wanted.

With `np.array(input, copy=False)`, a new array is always created. It will either point to the same block of memory as `input` if this latter was already a `ndarray` (that is, no waste of memory), or will create a new one "from scratch" if `input` wasn't. The interesting case is of course if `input` was a `ndarray`.

Using this new array in a function may or may not change the original input, depending on the function. You have to check the documentation of the function you want to use to see whether it returns a copy or not. The NumPy developers try hard to limit unnecessary copies (following the Python example), but sometimes it can't be avoided. The documentation should tell explicitly what happens, if it doesn't or it's unclear, please mention it.

`np.array(...)` may raise some exceptions if something goes awry. For example, trying to use a `dtype=float` with an input like `["STRING", 1]` will raise a `ValueError`. *However, I must admit I can't remember which exceptions in all the cases, please edit this post accordingly*.

Comment: Thanks that's extremely useful.  I think I'm going to stick with the numpy.array() function with the specific options for duck typing.  Three questions if I may: **1)** if I set copy = true and no change to the input is required, does python still copy it (and hence waste space)? What if the only thing changed is the shape? **2)** How does the copy=False work when the input variable S is passed into a function? **3)**What exception(s) will array() raise?

Comment: "In other terms, it's always easier to use np.array with the appropriate arguments." I think it comes down to style, I prefer `array = np.atleast_1d(array)` to `array = np.array(array, copy=False, ndim=1)`, though you're right `np.atleast_1d` calls `numpy.array` under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

When doing input validation for NumPy code, I always use `np.asarray`:

```
>>> np.asarray(np.array([1,2,3]))
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.asarray([1,2,3])
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.asarray((1,2,3))
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.asarray(1)
array(1)
>>> np.asarray(1).shape
()
```

This function has the nice feature that it only copies data when necessary; if the input is already an `ndarray`, the data is left in-place (only the type may be changed, because it also gets rid of that pesky `np.matrix`).

> The docstring for ndim says

That's the docstring for the function `np.ndim`, not the `ndim` attribute, which non-NumPy objects don't have. You could use that function, but the effect would be that the data might be copied twice, so instead do:

```
S = np.asarray(S)
(p, p2) = S.shape
```

This will raise a `ValueError` if `S.ndim != 2`.

[Final note: you don't need `;` in Python if you just follow the indentation rules. In fact, Python programmers eschew the semicolon.]

Comment: "Python programmers eschew the semicolon", is not _always_ correct. In fact there is an example in PEP 8 of good style with a semicolon: `if x == 4: print x, y; x, y = y, x`. Personally though, even in this case I would use two lines. In the OP's case, I completely agree, putting a `;` at the end of a normal line of code is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, I understand then the cause of the AttributeError.  However, I **want** to raise an error on a non-array input.  So it seems then I only need to add in a 'except ValueError:    # got here because S is a vector
 raise ValueError("blah blah blah");' after the first Except.  This way I can test for an array, test for a vector, and force a scalar array to (1,1).  Oh, and I know I need to drop the semicolons.  Habits are hard ...

Comment: @Hooked: the example in PEP8 is to show proper use of whitespace, not semicolons.

Comment: @user1686236: you can still force an array with shape `()` to shape `(1,1)` with `.reshape(1,1)`. `np.asarray` will already raise a `ValueError` for you when given the wrong input; consider giving it a `dtype` argument to ensure your input is numeric. E.g. `dtype=np.float`.

Comment: @larsmans If there is an example using semicolons in the official style guide to Python, couldn't one infer that the use of a semicolon isn't explicitly discouraged?

Comment: @Hooked: PEP-8 does say that "Compound statements (...) are generally discouraged" (and then it shows a bunch of them in its own examples). The `pep8` style checker will give a warning for any line containing a `;` terminator.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack-overflow. This comes down to almost a style choice, but the most common way I've seen to deal with this kind of situation is to convert the input to an array. Numpy provides some useful tools for this. `numpy.asarray` has already been mentioned, but here are a few more. `numpy.at_least1d` is similar to `asarray`, but reshapes () arrays to be (1,) `numpy.at_least2d` is the same as above but reshapes 0d and 1d arrays to be 2d, ie (3,) to (1, 3). The reason we convert "array_like" inputs to arrays is partly just because we're lazy, for example sometimes it can be easier to write `foo([1, 2, 3])` than `foo(numpy.array([1, 2, 3]))`, but this is also the design choice made within numpy itself. Notice that the following works:

```
>>> numpy.mean([1., 2., 3.])
>>> 2.0
```

In the docs for `numpy.mean` we can see that x should be "array_like".

> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> a : array_like
>     Array containing numbers whose mean is desired. If `a` is not an
>     array, a conversion is attempted.
> ```

That being said, there are situations when you want to only accept arrays as arguments and not all "array_like" types.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I've some more related questions about the duck typing with numpy.array, which I'll post on a different thread.